# OAuth flow with refresh tokens. Error 500

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am making a PHP application, that will use a single google drive account.

So as an administrator i first give permission to google drive account.
When permissions are accepted, i save the refresh token in a database.

After than, in a different URL, that will be used by clients, i am trying to authenticate.

Next, I pull the refresh token from database, and then a make a post request to:

```
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
```

with parameters:

```
$post_data = array(
    'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
    'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token' );
```

After a get successful response, I save the access_token but when i try to exchange it for credentials, i get this error Message:

```
An error occurred: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: '    
Error processing OAuth 2 request

Error 500
'
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CodeExchangeException' in ...
```

Am I missing something here?
Is the oauth flow i used correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get access token from refresh token, that access token itself is a credential and there is no exchange process after that. In credential, there are: 1. access token 2. refresh token. And you get credential in exchange of authorization code, not access token. So in your code, error occurred in process of trying to get access token in exchange of access token.

Comment: thnx for your reply. So, using refresh token i get a json obj that contains access_token and id_token. What should i do with this json obj? pass it to build service?

Comment: I'm not sure about what to do with that json object. However, there should be some abstraction regarding refresh token somewhere. I'm not really sure about google-api-php-client, but in google-api-python-client, Credentials.authorize automatically try to refresh token for you if it is expired so that from developer level, they don't even have to bother anything about refreshing. There should be some abstraction implemented regarding refreshing and you don't have to handle it yourself. Rather than handling refresh by yourself, I recommend you to take a closer look at documentation.